# How to properly set a PageView as the title for an AppBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to set a `PageView` as the `title` for an `AppBar`. However, when doing so I get the following error: "Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height ...". How can this be fixed?

Reference visual structure:

```
Scaffold:
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: PageView(),
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a width and height for the PageView. With `kToolbarHeight` it takes the height of the toolbar component of the AppBar. With `Expanded` it takes the available width of the default title space of AppBar.

Try this

```
appBar: AppBar(
        title: SizedBox(
          height: kToolbarHeight,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: PageView()),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```